# Relating Internal Nodes to External Nodes in a Proper Binary Tree

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

I am learning Binary Tree with ''Data Structures and Algorithms in Python"

When the author stats the "Relating Internal Nodes to External Nodes in a Proper Binary Tree", it reads

> Proposition 8.9: In a nonempty proper binary tree T , with `nE` external nodes and n I internal nodes, we have `n E` = `n I` +1.
>
> (``n E`,`n I` and h denote the number of nodes, number of external nodes, number of internal nodes,)

the author continued:

> Justiﬁcation: We justify this proposition by removing nodes from T and divid- ing them up into two “piles,” an internal-node pile and an external-node pile, until T becomes empty. The piles are initially empty. By the end, we will show that the external-node pile has one more node than the internal-node pile. We consider two cases:
>
> - Case 1: If T has only one node v, we remove v and place it on the external-node pile. Thus, the external-node pile has one node and the internal-node pile is empty.
> - Case 2: Otherwise (T has more than one node), we remove from T an (arbitrary) external node w and its parent v, which is an internal node. We place w on the external-node pile and v on the internal-node pile. If v has a parent u, then we reconnect u with the former sibling z of w, as shown in Figure 8.10. This operation, removes one internal node and one external node, and leaves the tree being a proper binary tree. Repeating this operation, we eventually are left with a ﬁnal tree consisting of a single node. Note that the same number of external and internal nodes have been removed and placed on their respective piles by the sequence of operations leading to this ﬁnal tree. Now, we remove the node of the ﬁnal tree and we place it on the external-node pile. Thus, the the external-node pile has one more node than the internal-node pile.

[image: Screen Shot 2018-11-30 at 1.14.14 PM]

I just start to learn algorithms but find the well-know author is ridiculous funny, he struggle such a detour to impove that n E`=`n I` +1, 
Yes, of couse, a leaf (external) is orginaite from an internal node one more. I think it is very stupid to prove '1 + 1 = 2' or "this is earth, aliens"

Am I missing some points?

Comment: Yes, make simple to be complex and complicated is the duty of the professors.

Comment: @JawSaw What exactly is your question? The proof seems correct and necessary. Do you just find the result obvious? Because intuition can be quite wrong when it comes to mathematical structures. A good exercise would be to try and prove the statement yourself using a different approach.

Comment: to verify the stupidity,leaf is from its parent. @merlyn

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, of course, a leaf (external) is originate from an internal node one more. I think it is very stupid to prove '1 + 1 = 2'

Not sure if I follow your proof. Consider the following:

1. Indeed, every external node has a parent (internal) node, except if the tree consists of one node, but
2. Two external nodes share the same parent (internal) node, so the above would lead to double counting, and
3. There can be several internal nodes that have no external nodes as direct children.

It is then to prove that the shortage of internal nodes mentioned in point 2 is compensated by the surplus of internal nodes mentioned in point 3.

Surely this can be proved in several ways, but to compare it with 1+1=2 is in my opinion an oversimplification.

On the other hand I would agree that the story of the two piles is a bit overkill, but it can help to visualise things. It would have sufficed to say that the difference between the number of internal and external nodes remains invariant with the removal operation.

### Alternative Proof

An alternative proof would have as second (recursive) step the removal of two sibling external nodes. First we must prove that such a pair can be found when the tree is not just one node:

Let's take a leaf that is has the longest distance to the root. Because the binary tree is proper, this node has a sibling. Also we know this sibling has no children, otherwise our chosen leaf was not the one with the longest distance to the root. So we conclude that indeed we can always find a pair of external sibling nodes.

This removal of a sibling pair turns their shared parent node into an external node. We note that we have maintained the "proper binary tree" property. So we remove 2 external nodes and turn one internal node to an external node. Thus we end up with one external and one internal node less. The invariance is maintained. We note that we can always repeat this operation until there is only one node left, which is then an external node.

This is not as trivial as 1 + 1 = 2, although I would understand if you had your preferences.